# Philippines - What is this symbol on a world aeronautical chart mean?

Tags: aeronautical-charts

[image]

Need help regarding this symbol. I've checked the legend and this symbol isn't there. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

It's a depiction of a large building, large enough to be usable as a landmark for navigation. The graphic roughly represents the shape of the structure.

In this case, it seems to be a structure associated with a powerplant:

[image: Google Earth image showing coal-fired power plant]

(Image from Google Earth)

Comment: FAA calls them "pictorial symbols".

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thank you so much.